# Why could WM_CHANGECBCHAIN be an important event to any app?

Tags: winapi, clipboard

Windows exposes the WM_CHANGECBCHAIN event which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-changecbchain).

What might be the reason why any app might be interested in this event?
Does it occur if any virus program hooks into the clipboard chain, and antivirus apps might want to be notified about this? Or what else might be the reason this event is exposed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#creating-a-clipboard-viewer-window

Comment: It's important for the integrity of the chain. If you use SetClipboardViewer you need to handle it as documented. But these days it's better to use AddClipboardFormatListener.